# PGP Certificate Conversion and EM Client

Tags: conversion, certificate, pgp

Trying to get "EM Client" to sign and decrypt messages using a PGP Key pair. It seems to accept certificates in other formats but not specifically PGP. It will accept (p12 pfx cer pem der arm). Does anyone know the easiest way to either convert the keys I have (asc or gpg) format and which one is best to use?

EM Client is an email client for Windows.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end? OpenPGP and X.509 keys/certificates are not compatible. While you could extract the keys and generate new certificates, you will still not be able to use OpenPGP with EM Client by converting the keys. There is barely ever a good reason to convert OpenPGP to X.509 keys, as the certificates cannot be converted anyway -- better directly create a new key pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, EM Client does not support PGP!
EM Client supports S/MIME. If you want to use that, you have to use a S/MIME certificate. Newer gpg versions can create them, but S/MIME uses a different trust model and you have to get a certificate from a CA to work without issues.

If you use S/MIME, the people you communicate with also need to use that. It is incompatible with PGP!

Answer (score 2):

At eM Client 7.1 PGP is integrated and supported.

Comment: Say what are you talking about exactly????? This is not an answer for [edit] and add some detail.

Comment: Previous answer notes that EM Client does not support PGP, but this answer notes that EM Client added PGP support beginning with version 7.1 It's not worded the best, but it does appear to be pretty clear to me, and helpful.

Comment: Menu (top Left) -> Tools -> Settings -> Signing and Encrypting -> Certificates and Keys -> Create PGP certificate

Comment: Then fill in your data, Key size (I recommend 4096 bits) an that's it.
You should have a key pair in "My certificates/keys" -> click right to share the public key with e-mail or something else.

Comment: http://www.emclient.com/?lang=en